# how to bind popup value to dynamically created textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

i am creating a Button and a textbox dynamically one by one in grid. My requirement is, if i click the button, the popup will show. and if i select the values from popup, i need to bind the corresponding row's textbox. Fr example, if i click the 5th row's button, i need to bind the popup item value to the 5th rows textbox. i struck on binding values to corresponding row's textbox. this may be simple one but i am unable to done this. this is my code.,

Xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btn_addnewrow" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Height="31"    Click="btn_addnewrow_Click"/>
     <Popup Name="popup" IsOpen="False" Placement="Mouse" VerticalOffset="15" HorizontalOffset="0" Margin="124,122,107,65">
         <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Coral">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="143">
                 <ListView Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="133" MouseDoubleClick="ListView1_MouseDoubleClick">
                    <ListViewItem Content="Coffie"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Tea"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Milk"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListViewItem>
                </ListView>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

cs:

```
    public int count = 0;
    public Button btn1;
    public Button btn2;
    public TextBox txt1;

    private void btn_addnewrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating Rows..
        RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
        row0.Height = new GridLength(40);
        grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row0);

        //Creating columns..
        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();

        col0.Width = new GridLength(50);
        col1.Width = new GridLength(100);
        col2.Width = new GridLength(70);


        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);

        int i = count;

        ////1st Column button
        btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        btn1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn1, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn1, 0);
        btn1.Tag = btn1;
        btn1.Click += btnBindList_Click;
        grid1.Children.Add(btn1);         

        //2nd column Textbox 
        txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        txt1.Name = "txt" + i;
        Grid.SetRow(txt1, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(txt1, 1);
        txt1.Tag = txt1;
        grid1.Children.Add(txt1);

        count++;
    }

    private void btnBindList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          ?
          ?
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt1.Text = (ListView1.SelectedItem as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a usercontrol with button, textbox and popup. This usercontrol should set to the cell template or item template of gridview or listview. The textbox is bound to selected value of popup listview. So when user open popup and choose the value, the selected value will update in corresponding textbox.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ListView1, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2"/>
    <ToggleButton Content="Select" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" x:Name="btn"/>
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}" Placement="Bottom"
           StaysOpen="False"
           IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsChecked}">
        <ListView Name="ListView1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="194"
                  Height="133">
            <ListViewItem Content="Coffie"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Tea"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Milk"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i am creating textbox and button dynamically. this code is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Binding, you need to creat a viewmodel,a class. And binding it to Button and TextBox. When you click a button,get the viewmodel, and set it's value by selecting in listview.

The code is very confused, but you can debug and rewrite it by yourself.

```
public int count = 0;
    public Button btn1;
    public Button btn2;
    public TextBox txt1;

    private void btn_addnewrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating Rows..
        RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
        row0.Height = new GridLength(40);
        grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row0);

        //Creating columns..
        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();

        col0.Width = new GridLength(50);
        col1.Width = new GridLength(100);
        col2.Width = new GridLength(70);


        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);

        int i = count;
        Test t = new Test();
        ////1st Column button
        btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        btn1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        Grid.SetRow(btn1, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(btn1, 0);
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = t;
        btn1.SetBinding(Button.TagProperty, binding);
        btn1.Click += btnBindList_Click;
        grid1.Children.Add(btn1);

        Binding binding1 = new Binding("Content");
        binding1.Source = t;
        //2nd column Textbox 
        txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
        txt1.Name = "txt" + i;
        txt1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding1);
        Grid.SetRow(txt1, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(txt1, 1);
        txt1.Tag = txt1;
        grid1.Children.Add(txt1);

        count++;
    }

    private void btnBindList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        popup.IsOpen = true;
        t = ((Button)sender).Tag as Test;
    }
    Test t;
    private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        t.Content = (ListView1.SelectedItem as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}

class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string content;

    public string Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```